# Slack modal validation

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I need to do custom validation in a slack modal window.
The logic is that I first open the modal window with one input field, then update the window with other fields depending on the selection in that field.
When I click submit, I want to update the modal window with errors, if any. Otherwise the data should be submitted.

```
      await ack();
      const settings = await statusSource.getConfig();
      const userName = body.user.username;
      const selectedProjectId = action.selected_option.value;

      const userRedmineData = await this.#getRedmineData({
        username: userName,
        entities: ["projects", "issues", "activities"],
        params: {
          getDataBasedOnLastTimeEntry: false,
          projectId: selectedProjectId,
        },
      });

      const { projects, issues, activities } = userRedmineData;

      const initialValues = {
        [actions.modal.project]: projectOptionsMapper({
          id: action.selected_option.value,
          name: action.selected_option.text.text,
        }),
      };

      const meta = JSON.parse(body.view.private_metadata);

      await client.views.update({
        view_id: body.view.id,
        hash: body.view.hash,
        view: getTimeEntryModalStructure({
          settings,
          projects: projects,
          issues: issues,
          activities,
          fieldsMapper: modalFieldMappers.extended,
          initialValues,
          meta,
        }),
      });
```

That's my update logic. It's work fine.

```
     await ack ()
      const settings = await statusSource.getConfig();
      const responseData = getModalValues(view);
      const error = getRedmineTimeEntryErrors({ data: responseData, settings });

      if (error[actions.modal.hours] || error[actions.modal.time_range]) {
        const userRedmineData = await this.#getRedmineData({
          username: body.user.username,
          entities: ["projects", "issues", "activities"],
          params: {
            getDataBasedOnLastTimeEntry: false,
            projectId: responseData.projectId,
          },
        });
        const { projects, issues, activities } = userRedmineData;

        const initialValues = {
          [actions.modal.project]: projectOptionsMapper({
            id: body.view.blocks[0].element.initial_option.value,
            name: body.view.blocks[0].element.initial_option.text.text,
          }),
          [actions.modal.issue]: issueOptionsMapper({
            id: body.view.blocks[1].element.initial_option.value,
            subject: issues.find((el) => el.id == responseData.issueId).subject,
          }),
          [actions.modal.date]: responseData.date,
          [actions.modal.hours]: responseData.hours,
          [actions.modal.comment]: responseData.comment,
          [actions.modal.time_range]: responseData.time_range,
        };
        const meta = JSON.parse(body.view.private_metadata);

        await client.views.update({
          view_id: body.view.id,
          hash: body.view.hash,
          view: getTimeEntryModalStructure({
            settings,
            projects,
            issues,
            activities,
            fieldsMapper: modalFieldMappers.extended,
            initialValues,
            meta,
            errors: error,
          }),
        });
      } else {
        const { issueId, date, hours, comment, activity, timeRange } =
          responseData;

        const userName = body.user.username;
        const userToken = await RedmineUsers.getTokenByLogin({
          login: userName,
        });
        const redmineTime = new RedmineTime(userToken);

        await redmineTime.create({
          issueId,
          hours,
          comments: comment,
          spentOn: date,
          activity,
          timeRange,
        });

        const meta = JSON.parse(body.view.private_metadata);

        await client.chat.delete({
          channel: body.user.id,
          ts: meta.messageTs,
        });
        await client.chat.postMessage(
          getSuccessTimeEntryMessageStructure({
            channel: body.user.id,
            settings,
          })
        );
      }
```

That's my create logic on button submit action. I can't get an interface update unless I pass additional parameters to ack.
Error: An API error occurred: not_found

I tried this option(call ack with additional parameters), then the update works, but submit causes an error and does not close the modal window. How can I do this cleanly and correctly?

```
      await ack({
        response_action: "update",
        view: body.view,
      });
```